# TaskManager Trace with ->Remove-TimeStamp, trying to understand

Tags: timestamp, pyflink

Looking at the TaskManager logs I see the following traces:

SlidingEventTimeWindows, Extract-Timestamp -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> Remove-Timestamp -> _stream_key_by_map_operator

I would like to know what the Remove-Timestamp step means, what function it would be carrying out, and if this is causing me to lose the TimeStamps before the Key_by function. In the latter case, if it is true, how can I avoid it?

The underlying problem is that in a generation of SlidingEventTimeWindows windows, their emission never occurs, and it seems that the cause is that there are no Watermarks although I have assigned them.

Here is part of my code:

`watermark_strategy_i = WatermarkStrategy.for_bounded_out_of_orderness(Duration.of_seconds(30)).with_timestamp_assigner(MyTimestampAssigner())

data_stream_t_wt = data_stream_t.assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(watermark_strategy_i)

first_window_stream = data_stream_t_wt.key_by(lambda x: (x[4],
x[5])).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5).Time.minutes(1))).trigger(EventTimeTrigger()).process(TransformRowProcessWindowFunction_i()
`
I would like to know how to find out the real cause of the problem, so that in the end the normal emission of the windows occurs